# Как в C++ определить разрешение изображения и поместить его в массив?

Tags: c++, изображения

Как определить разрешение изображения и поместить изображение в массив?
Windows, Qt - я знаю только этот фреймворк.

Comment: В стандарте языка нет функций работы с изображениями. Можно использовать API операционной системы или функции специальных библиотек. Уточните платформу (Windows, Linux, ...) и используемые библиотеки графического интереса (Qt, MFC, wxWidgets ...) , если вы их используете.

Comment: Windows, Qt - я знаю только этот фреймворк

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте класс [QImage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html)

```
 QImage image("my_photo.jpg");
 QSize s= image.size(); // размер

 image.setPixelColor( 1,1, image.pixelColor(0,0) );// работа с пикселями

 image.bits();// Доступ к низкоуровневым двоичным данным
```

Comment: А OpenGL или OpenCL можно в этих целях использовать?

Comment: OpenGL  предназначен для отображения изображения, а не для обработки изображения. Вы путаете технологии. OpenCL - теоретически... но не думаю что труд затраченый для отправки программы в видеокарту, суть которой - прочесть байты с смещением - нет смысла.